# Error Connecting to IB using ibapi python

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I have been running IB Gateway client on my localhost.

I need to use some basic apis like account details order execution and view orders.

But When I use ibapi as python wrapper around IB APIs, it gives me an error

```
>>> from ibapi.client import EClient
>>> from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper  
>>> class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
...      def __init__(self):
...          EClient.__init__(self, self) 
... 
>>> app = IBapi()
>>> app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123534)
Disconnected; resetting connection
```

Can someone help me out here?

Where IB gateway console is here

```
 runtime path : 

root:dist/ibgroup.web.core.iblink.router.clientportal.gw.jar:build/lib/runtime/*
 config file  : root/conf.yaml
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/home/parkar10/clientportal-gw/build/lib/runtime/netty-common-4.1.15.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
 -> mount demo on /demo
Java Version: 11.0.16
****************************************************
version: bae7d315fc7f01dbb300e6d20379b83d9d590689 Wed, 7 Jul 2021 18:41:40 -0400
****************************************************
This is the Client Portal Gateway
for any issues, please contact api@ibkr.com
and include a copy of your logs
****************************************************
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html
****************************************************
Open https://localhost:7497 to login
App demo is available after you login under: https://localhost:7497/demo#/
```

Logs are showing something like this

```
14:12:10.689 WARN  vert.x-eventloop-thread-0 DefaultChannelPipeline : An 

exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 4150490000000009763130302e2e313537
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 4150490000000009763130302e2e313537
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1106)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```